# IA32 Register Address

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, cpu-registers, x86

I have a few inter-meshing problems that are throwing me off. I am doing an assignment where I must review assembly code in `gdb` to find the correct input that makes the C program work. To test this, I enter a test string which consists of some numbers and step through/read the assembly to predict its behavior and figure out a solution.

Here's the main problem: at one point, my entire input string is stored in the `%eax` register. When I call:

```
x/a $eax
```

It returns a hex which I assume to be the address of `%eax`. At this point last byte of the hex varies, depending on the input. Shortly after the program calls `strtol()` on the input string, removes the first number from the string, and places the shortened string back into `%eax`.

Here's where things get confusing: seemingly no matter how long the original input was or how long the appended input is, when I call `x/a` on `$eax`, the last byte of the hex value that is returned seems to always equal 32. This is a problem because there is a `cmp` test shortly after that uses the last byte of the `%eax` address, and the number 32 causes the program to crash intentionally.

Am I misunderstanding the use of `x/a` and, in fact, the hex I'm returned is not an address at all? Can the size of an input influence the address of a registry? Any other helpful hints that could help me in this situation?

Thanks very much

Comment: I put in quite a lot more than 3 chars! When I call `x/s $eax`, it returns my entire input string before the call to `strtol()`. Unless there's some subtlety I'm missing, it seems to be coping.

Comment: In this case, `%eax` *contains* the address of your string, i.e. it contains a pointer. Obviously registers don't *have* addresses. If this is the case, then obviously your input will not affect what goes into `%eax`, since the address of a string doesn't change just because you store something different in it.

Comment: @user3635296 Don't feed the troll. Use flags instead( located at the left side of the comment ).

Comment: @PaulGriffiths ah! That makes a lot of sense, thank you. In that case, when I call x/a, am I getting the address of the string? If so, what influences the last byte of this number?

Comment: `x` displays the contents of an address. `x $eax` shows the contents of the address contained in `%eax`. `x/s $eax` shows the contents of the address contained in `%eax` as if the address contained in `%eax` points to the start of a string. `x/a $eax` shows the contents of the address contained in `%eax` as if that address points to *another* address. So as to "what influences the last byte of this number" - the contents of your string are what influences it, since `x/a` is trying to interpret the first four characters of your string not as a string, but as a 32 bit address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your comments says that "When I call `x/s $eax`, it returns my entire input string before the call to `strtol()`".

If this is the case, then `%eax` contains the address of a string, and `x $eax` will attempt to display the contents of that address.

`x/s $eax` displays the contents as a string, so it will interpret the byte at `$eax` as a character and display it, do the same for `$eax + 1`, and so on until it encounters the terminating null. According to your comment, this is exactly what happens when you do `x/s $eax`.

`x/a $eax` displays the contents of that address as another address. In other words, it's going to take the first four bytes of your string, and display the 32 bit address that would have that same bit pattern. This interpreted "address" value is unlikely to be in any way meaningful to you. In other words, it might look like an address, but it's highly unlikely to actually be the address of anything your program uses, except by chance.

If `%eax` contained the address of a pointer variable, *then* running `x/a` on it would be meaningful, because then another address actually would be stored at the address contained in that register.

As a demonstration, consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(char * c) {
    char * p = c;
}

int main(void) {
    char * c = "Hello, world!";
    printf("Expected x/a output: 0x");
    for ( size_t i = 8; i > 0; --i ) {
        printf("%X", c[i - 1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    myfunc(c);
    return 0;
}
```

In this particular case, the parameter is going to get passed to `myfunc()` in the `%eax` register, so if we break on the line `char * p = c;` and run `x/s $eax`, we ought to see `"Hello, world!"` displayed, because the `%eax` register contains the contents of the `char *` variable which points to that string.

If we then run `x/a $eax`, since I'm running this on a 64 bit machine which has 8 byte addresses, we'll get an "address" that is composed of the ASCII code for `'w'` (which is `0x77`), the 8th character of the string, followed by the ASCII code for `' '` (which is `0x20`), the 7th character of the string, followed by the ASCII code for `','` (which is `0x2C`), and so on all the way to `'H'`. The loop in `main()` calculates what this should look like. It goes from back to front because the x86 architecture is little-endian.

If we run `x/c`, we'll get the individual characters of the string.

So, let's look at the gdb output:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ gdb ./addr
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/paul/src/c/scratch/addr...done.
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   void myfunc(char * c) {
4       char * p = c;
5   }
6   
7   int main(void) {
8       char * c = "Hello, world!";
9       printf("Expected x/a output: 0x");
10      for ( size_t i = 8; i > 0; --i ) {
(gdb) break 4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400604: file addr.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/paul/src/c/scratch/addr 
Expected x/a output: 0x77202C6F6C6C6548

Breakpoint 1, myfunc (c=0x40073c "Hello, world!") at addr.c:4
4       char * p = c;
(gdb) x/s $eax
0x40073c:    "Hello, world!"
(gdb) x/a $eax
0x40073c:   0x77202c6f6c6c6548
(gdb) x/c $eax
0x40073c:   72 'H'
(gdb) x/c $eax + 1
0x40073d:   101 'e'
(gdb) x/c $eax + 2
0x40073e:   108 'l'
(gdb)
```

we see exactly what we're expecting.

As an example of where `x/a` would actually make sense, let's change the program to pass a pointer to a pointer, so that the address contained in `%eax` (actually changed to `%rax` here, since I'm on a 64 bit system, and need the full 8 byte register to hold the address of a stack variable, which will be quite high - in the first example, I was passing the address of the statically allocated string literal `"Hello, world!"`, which was stored at a low enough address to easily fit into the 4-byte part of the `%rax` register which is `%eax` on an x64 processor) really does point to another address:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(char ** c) {
    char ** p = c;
}

int main(void) {
    char * c = "Hello, world!";
    printf("Contents of c, and expected x/a output: %p\n", (void *)c);
    myfunc(&c);
    return 0;
}
```

and the gdb output this time:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/c/scratch$ gdb ./addr2
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/paul/src/c/scratch/addr2...done.
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   void myfunc(char ** c) {
4       char ** p = c;
5   }
6   
7   int main(void) {
8       char * c = "Hello, world!";
9       printf("Contents of c, and expected x/a output: %p\n", (void *)c);
10      myfunc(&c);
(gdb) break 4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005b4: file addr2.c, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/paul/src/c/scratch/addr2 
Contents of c, and expected x/a output: 0x4006b0

Breakpoint 1, myfunc (c=0x7fffffffe478) at addr2.c:4
4       char ** p = c;
(gdb) x/a $rax
0x7fffffffe478: 0x4006b0
(gdb)
```

Here, the parameter - and therefore the `%rax` register - contains the address of `char * c` in `main()`, and `c` contains the address of the `"Hello, world!"` string. So when we display the contents of the address contained in `%rax` as an address, we get the address of the `"Hello, world!"` string, which unlike the first example above, actually is a meaningful address.

Comment: awesome, if what you say is correct, it appears that `%eax` is holding a char* to my input string. If you have time, I suppose the only confusing part is the `x/a` business. To obtain the 32 value I referenced previously, the program calls `mov` on `(%eax), %eax`, and then stores the last byte of `%eax`. I still am not seeing how my string is affecting this number - will the length alone affect this value? It seems that varying the length is doing...well..not that

Comment: Additionally, if I call `x/c` it returns: 32 '[first char]'
Is it returning the value of that piece of space?

Comment: `0x32` is the ASCII code for the character `'2'`. `32` in decimal is the ASCII code for the space character. `x/c` is telling you what the first character in your string is (presuming `$eax` is still pointing to it at that point in the code - it won't be if you start modifying the contents of `%eax`).

Comment: thank you so much, this helped explain it perfectly!