# IA32 Assembly cmp on strings

Tags: string, assembly, x86, cmp

I'm having some trouble reverse engineering some IA32 assembly code. Namely, these lines:

```
   0x08049d6d <+206>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
   0x08049d70 <+209>:   mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
   0x08049d73 <+212>:   mov    %edx,%ecx
   0x08049d75 <+214>:   sub    %eax,%ecx
   0x08049d77 <+216>:   mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x08049d79 <+218>:   cmp    $0x5,%eax
   0x08049d7c <+221>:   je     0x8049d83 <level_6+228>
```

Here, the `$edx` register is holding a string and the `$eax` register is holding the same string, only with the character at index 0 removed.

The confusion arises from the `sub` instruction at step 214. It seems, no matter what the two characters are at the start of the strings, it comes out to 1. Is it comparing the lengths of the strings?

Additionally what does calling `cmp` on two strings compare?

Many thanks!

EDIT:

Earlier, two strings are being cmp'd:

```
0x08049d68 <+201>: cmp -0xc(%ebp),%eax 
0x08049d6b <+204>: jb 0x8049cfa <level_6+91>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like we've [been here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23706625/ia32-register-address).

Registers can't "hold strings", unless they're very short ones. What you're got there are *addresses* of strings, or pointers to (the first characters of) strings. If `%edx` holds a pointer to the string, and `%eax` holds "the same string, only with the character at index 0 removed", then `%eax` almost certainly points to the *second* character of the string.

That being the case, if you subtract one from the other, of course you're always going to get `1`, because the second character of the string is always one byte further along than the first character. It doesn't matter what the characters are, because you're comparing *addresses*.

The `cmp` instruction is clearly not comparing two strings - it's comparing the literal number `5` with the contents of `%eax`, which at that point will be your `1`, the difference between the two pointers. So the `cmp` instruction compares `5` with `1`, and if they're equal - which they're obviously not, in this case - `jmp`s to `0x8049d83`.

That being said, I suspect you have this back to front. If `%edx` points to the start of the string, and `%eax` points to the second character, then the `sub` instruction should be giving you `-1`, not `1`. `%edx` and `%eax` are probably the other way round. This routine seems to be designed to `jmp` to `0x8049d83` when `%edx` points to the sixth character of the string that `%eax` points to.

Comment: thanks again for your help. It explains the problem very well - what happens then when two registers holding addresses to distinct and different strings are `cmp`'d? For example, the ones I included in the edit to my original post

Comment: Exactly the same thing, it'll just compare the addresses, which obviously will not be equal if they point to totally different strings.